# execute job immediately

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I try to run emergency job immediately after scheduled with quartz. 
my code is below.I give current time as startTime. 
Bıt it takes 30- 40 seconds to run job after schedule.How can run immediately.

```
// Trigger the job to run now, and then repeat every 40 seconds 
jobTrigger= newTrigger() 
.withIdentity(Long.toString(emergencyJob.getId()), Long.toString(emergencyJob.getVariant().getId())) 
.withPriority(emergencyJob.getPriority()) 
.startAt(new Date(ctime)) 
.withSchedule(simpleSchedule().withMisfireHandlingInstructionFireNow() 
) 
.build(); 

scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, jobTrigger);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also fire it with:

```
scheduler.triggerJob(jobDetail.getKey());
```

Comment: I am getting following exception.The Job(1.187)referenced by the trigger does not exist

Comment: Now I am able to trigger job without exception.Still I have an 20 second delay.I configured Quartz with Jboss and am using EJB.Is there any special configuration in JBoss configuration to trigger immediately job

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess (it's been a while since I've used quartz), but since you create the `Date` instance before you actually call `build()`, it may not be able to meet that time constraint and simply fires 40 seconds later when the next scheduled trigger fires. Try something like this to confirm:

```
.startAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000))
```

Play with the 1000ms value to suit your needs. This is to give it a bit more time to meet the first scheduled trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Probably bit late, but maybe someone will find this useful. I had same issue with quartz on JBoss AS (triggers executed late - approximately 20-30 seconds, for no obvious reason). I came to conclusion that this is caused by some bug in JBoss. Same application worked fine on glassfish. I have changed only PU in order to work with eclipse link and other persistence worked fine on JBoss, so I don't suppose issue there. This behaviour occured only when using quartz database task store, with RAM store it worked fine. 
To answear the question. If you use database taskstore, consider changing it to RAM store for me that caused triggers to be fired at time.